# Can I use a common table expression within a Create Table Statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create tables in mysql workbench (version 8.0.21) to help give me an edge in my fantasy baseball league. I have working code listed that I'm trying to make more concise so I can add more calculations in without it being excessively long. The working code is below...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS hitting2019;
CREATE TABLE hitting2019
    SELECT 
        playerID, 
        (SUM(R) + SUM(H) + (SUM(2B) * 2) + (SUM(3B) * 3) + (SUM(HR) * 4) + SUM(RBI) + (SUM(SB) * 2) + (SUM(CS) * -2) + SUM(BB) + SUM(HBP)) AS points19
    FROM batting
    WHERE yearID = 2019
    GROUP BY playerID;

SET @avgpoints19 = (SELECT AVG(points19) FROM hitting2019 WHERE points19 <> 0); 

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS avgg2019;
CREATE TABLE avgg2019
    SELECT 
        playerID,
        ROUND((points19 - @avgpoints),0) AS points_above_repl19
    FROM hitting2019
    GROUP BY playerID;
```

The query that is not working is my first attempt at nesting a with statement within a create table statement.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS hitting2019;
CREATE TABLE hitting2019 AS
WITH cte (playerID, points19) AS
    (SELECT 
        playerID, 
        (SUM(R) + SUM(H) + (SUM(2B) * 2) + (SUM(3B) * 3) + (SUM(HR) * 4) + SUM(RBI) + (SUM(SB) * 2) + (SUM(CS) * -2) + SUM(BB) + SUM(HBP)) AS points19
    FROM batting
    WHERE yearID = 2019
    GROUP BY playerID)
SELECT 
        ROUND((points19/g),2),
        ROUND((points19 - (SELECT AVG(points19) FROM hitting2019)),0) AS points_above_repl19
FROM cte c, batting b;
```

It says that "WITH is not valid at this position in this server version" however I can't figure out why this is because as far as I know it should be allowed.

Comment: The error message does not seem to come from MySQL. Are you sure your query gets executed in the first place?

Comment: it runs in mysql 8 , which version are you using

Comment: Correct it won't even let me execute the query and I'm using the most recent version.

Comment: the problem doesn't come from that create, maybe another query is faulty

Comment: Please create a fiddle in https://dbfiddle.uk/ or https://www.db-fiddle.com/ so we can debug your issue.

Comment: What do you need me to include besides what I provided above?

Comment: @AriGordon . . . You would appear to be using a version of MySQL that does not support CTEs.

Comment: I ended up reinitializing my database and it began to allow me to use WITH statements, so it just needed a restart I guess. Also had to increase the DBMS connection read time, all solved.